# blank data being inserted when trying to insert from PHP variable to MY SQL server

Tags: php, mysql

this is my php page .I am sending data to $_post["name"],$_post["myHttpData"],$_post["address"]by an android application .I have tried writing these value in text file to check successful reception of data .The data is being received but a blank row (all fields blank) is being inserted when I send data .

```
    <?php

       $con=mysqli_connect("fdb2.biz.nf","1463950_rtr","tcp123","1463950_rtr");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }
    $data=$_post["myHttpData"];

    $data1=$_post["name"];
    $data2=$_post["address"];
    $sql="INSERT INTO SMS (sender,body,time)
    VALUES
    ('$data','$data1','$data2')";
      if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
      {
      die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
      }
    echo "1 record added";

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I have also tried using

```
 $sql="INSERT INTO SMS (`sender`,`body`,`time`)
    VALUES
    ('$data','$data1','$data2')";
```

But it also produces same results .

Comment: Have you tried using $_POST all capital case instead of $_post.  Also, a side note - you should use prepared statements to help protect against SQL injection.

Comment: Are you sure you want to assign the data to the fields: myHttpData->sender, name->body, address->time  ?

Answer (score -1):

Php variables are case sensitive. You need to specify `$_POST`, instead of `$_post`. 
Since there was nothing in `$_post[...]`, the `$data` fields take empty strings.

Comment: data is being received into the variable I am able to write them in files using the code <?php $data=$_POST["myHttpData"]; $data1=$_POST["name"]; $data2=$_POST["address"]; file_put_contents('myTextFile.txt',$data); file_put_contents('test1.txt',$data1); file_put_contents('test2.txt',$data2); ?>

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that you used single quotes instead of double quotes. In php, single quoted strings are processed "as is", while double quoted strings will look for variables and evaluate them. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

see if this works:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO SMS (sender,body,time)
VALUES
('".$data."','".$data1."','".$data2."')";
```

**EDIT:oops I see you used double quotes.**

try

```
 echo $sql;
```

see if your query is what you expected.

Comment: wait nvm you used double quotes, what am I thinking

Comment: I have tried that too but still it doesn't work .I am getting the same results .